# How many topological orderings exist for a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Given a directed and acyclic graph G(V,E) is there any way to determine the exact number of topological orderings it can have? I know the minimum is 1 if it contains a Hamiltonian path, but can the maximum number be determined ?

Comment: Assuming that the graph is directed and acyclic (which is has to be for a topological ordering to make sense), if the graph has a Hamiltonian path then there is a $\mathit{unique}$ topological sort ordering, not just a minimum of $1$.

Answer (score 9):

Of course there is a way -- just enumerate all of the topological orderings and count them as you go!

On the other hand, this is very slow. The general problem of determining the exact count in reasonable time is usually phrased as counting the [linear extensions of a partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension), and is known to be hard. More precisely, it is [#P-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete), so it cannot be done in polynomial time unless P=NP.

Comment: Let me rephrase it a little then, are there any types of directed and acyclic graphs for which the number topological orderings can be easily determined ?

Comment: @Alex Yes, for example if the graph looks like [Young tableau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau), then you can use the [hook length formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula). Of course, there are also other special cases, but that one is perhaps the most interesting.